# How to fix DetailView is missing a QuerySet Error?

Tags: python, django, detailview

When I try to use DetailView to view my posts I keep getting an exception error.

ImproperlyConfigured at /musician_details/1/
DetailView is missing a QuerySet. Define DetailView.model, DetailView.queryset, or override DetailView.get_queryset().
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/musician_details/1/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:
DetailView is missing a QuerySet. Define DetailView.model, DetailView.queryset, or override DetailView.get_queryset().
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py, line 69, in get_queryset
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:
['F:\Full Stack\Django\Django Project\Test',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\python38.zip',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\DLLs',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\lib',
'C:\Program Files\Python38',
'C:\Users\Tanim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sun, 19 Sep 2021 07:44:37 +0000

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from home import models


class IndexView(ListView):
  

    context_object_name = 'musician_list'
    model = models.Musician
    template_name = 'first_app/index.html'


class MusicianDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'musician'
    model = models.Musician
    template_name = 'first_app/musician_details.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.       
class Musician(models.Model):    
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name        
   
class Album(models.Model):
    artist=models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date=models.DateField()    
    rating=(
    (1,"Worst"),
    (2,"Bad"),
    (3,"Not Bad"),
    (4,"Good"),
    (5,"Excellent!"),    
    )        
    num_Stars=models.IntegerField(choices=rating)
          
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name +", Rating: " +str(self.num_Stars)
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

app_name = "home"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('musician_details/<pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='musician_details'),    
]
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'first_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<ul>

{% for musician in musician_list %}

<li><a href="{% url 'home:musician_details' pk=musician.pk %}">{{musician.first_name}} {{musician.last_name}}</a> </li>  

{% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

musician_details.html

```
{% extends 'first_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<h3>Musician Details:</h3>
<p>{{musician.first_name}} {{musician.last_name}}</p>
<p>{{musician.instrument}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, you basically made two mistakes. I missed the second one.

Comment: plz, explain my 2nd mistake( Detailview). I don't understand.

Comment: I think your IDE suggests you available objects in `views.py`. Since you imported `DetailView` in `views.py`, it is also suggested. You mistakenly choose `DetailView` but you create `MusicianDetail` for your detail views so you need to use `MusicianDetail`, not the parent class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DetailView URL pattern in `urls.py` is wrong.

You need to use `/<int:pk>/` not `/<pk>/`.

You also used `DetailView` so fix it to be `MusicianDetail`. That is, You call your musician detail view `MusicianDetail`, so in order to have valid URLs, you have to use `MusicianDetail` in your `urls.py`. `DetailView` is nothing but parent class to create detail view in the Django projects.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('musician_details/<int:pk>/', views. MusicianDetail.as_view(), name='musician_details'),    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

model = Musician
after works
and
you do urls.py a int:pk then works right

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

**views.py:**

```
class MusicianDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'musician'
    model = Musician
    template_name = 'first_app/musician_details.html'
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('musician_details/<int:pk>/', views.MusicianDetail.as_view(), 
name='musician_details'),    
]
```